# Proof that if $ab < ac$ with $a > 0$, then $b<c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here $a,\;b,\;c\in\mathbb Z$.

I cannot for the life of me prove this statement and it's been annoying me for a while now.

Comment: I'm guessing that you actually have $a>0$ instead of $c>0$. Otherwise, the statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Ekesh's comment solved it for me, I feel very stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove the contrapositive: If $b \geq c$, then $ab \geq ac$.

This is true since $ a > 0$.

Comment: But you are supposed to *start* with the hypothesis, not end up with it. If what you said was right, you could have equally well said that if $ab<ac$ then *we just cancel* $a$'s and we are left with $b<c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $ab < ac$, then $a(c -b) > 0$. Since $a > 0$, it follows that $c - b >0$, that is, $b <c$.